# Why output from vertex shader is being corrupted when an unsued output is not passed. (OpenGL/GLSL)

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm receiving three attributes in the vertex shader and passing them to the fragment shader. If I omit one particular channel, that is not used in the frament shader at all, the fragment shader produces invalid output.

I reduced the code to the following simple examples:

### A. (corrrect)

```
//Vertex Shader GLSL
#version 140
in vec3 a_Position;
in uvec4 a_Joint0;
in vec4 a_Weight0;


// it doesn't matter if flat is specified or not for the joint0 (apparently)
// out uvec4 o_Joint0; 
flat out vec4 o_Joint0;
flat out vec4 o_Weight0;

layout (std140) uniform WorldParams
{
    mat4 ModelMatrix;
};
void main()
{
    o_Joint0=a_Joint0;
    o_Weight0=a_Weight0;
    vec4 pos = ModelMatrix * vec4(a_Position, 1.0);
    gl_Position =  pos;
}
```

```
//Fragment Shader GLSL
#version 140

flat in uvec4 o_Joint0;
flat in vec4 o_Weight0;
out vec4 f_FinalColor;

void main() 
{
    f_FinalColor=vec4(0,0,0,1);
    f_FinalColor.rgb += (o_Weight0.xyz + 1.0) / 4.0+(o_Weight0.z + 1.0) / 4.0;
}
```

VS sends down to the FS the attributes o_Joint0 and o_Weight0, the fragment shader produces this correct output:

[image: correct_output]

### B. (incorrrect)

```
//Vertex Shader GLSL
#version 140
in vec3 a_Position;
in uvec4 a_Joint0;
in vec4 a_Weight0;


flat out vec4 o_Weight0;

layout (std140) uniform WorldParams
{
    mat4 ModelMatrix;
};
void main()
{
    o_Weight0=a_Weight0;
    vec4 pos = ModelMatrix * vec4(a_Position, 1.0);
    gl_Position =  pos;
}
```

```
//Fragment Shader GLSL
#version 140

flat in vec4 o_Weight0;
out vec4 f_FinalColor;

void main() 
{
    f_FinalColor=vec4(0,0,0,1);
    f_FinalColor.rgb += (o_Weight0.xyz + 1.0) / 4.0+(o_Weight0.z + 1.0) / 4.0;
}
```

VS sends down to the FS the attribute o_Weight0, as you can see the only thing omitted in both shaders was o_Joint0, the fragment shader produces this in incorrect output:

[image: incorrect_output]

Comment: How are you setting up the attributes in your C code?

Comment: Interestingly, your "correct" shader should not compile, because passing integral data types to the fragment shader (`uvec4`) require a `flat` interpolation qualifier, there is no support for interpolating integral types.

Comment: Actually that is a left over of my tests, I have the shader working with **flat** in both attributes. I assumed because no interpolation is possible GLSL used flat for the joints, as it is working, no problem compiling on Nvidia nor Intel. I will edit the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score -2):

First, try completely omitting the `a_Joint0` variable from the vertex shader (do not load it to the vertex shader at all, not even as a buffer).

If this does not work, try reverting your code back to before you omitted the variable and see if it works again, and then try and find out how it is actually affecting the fragment shader.

Comment: That is what I did, that is explained and showed in the example. When joints are omitted it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry... Ok, can you edit your question and upload the class of where the variables are changed into buffers and uploaded to vertex shader as well as the rendering functions; I want to see how they are uploaded because your shaders seem to be alright.

Comment: I can't, it is a too complex system to distill, many classes, many lines.... Anyway, Could that behavior be explained by sending wrong buffers ? besides the data in those buffers is correct, as it is rendering complex stuff without problems. I just found out about this doing some testing in those complex shaders.

Comment: _"Anyway, Could that behavior be explained by sending wrong buffers"_ - Yes, thats why I was asking to see how your buffers were uploaded to the shaders... Ok, but since you cannot seem to upload your code, (and assuming this is how your allocating attribute slots for your previous buffer : `a_Position` at "0",  `a_Joint0` at "1" and `a_Weight0` at "2"), instead try `a_Position` at "0",  `a_Weight0` at "1"; completely remove `a_Joint0` and replace it with `a_Weight0`.

Comment: How/Why sending wrong buffers could explain that behavior ? that is the answer I'm looking for. Can you explain one possible scenario ?

Comment: There are multiple ways a buffer could be wrongly allocated; wrong attribute slot (layout) allocation of the buffers - even accessing the incorrect layout in the shaders, incorrect enabling of vertex attribute slots (arrays to be precise). **This why I need you to upload the code** where you load your data as buffers in attribute slots/arrays to the shader. I can help you if I know where you are going wrong. (At **least** the code where you are allocating your slots and data to the shaders (it should not be very big for that matter)).